# jsgrid on firebase. how to put data on a table

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsgrid

how can I use jsgrid to present data on a table like the one jsgrid uses

i tried retrieving data as said by this documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-reading-data-get

```
$.getJSON("/*url of databse*/.json",
function(data){
  clients = data;
  console.log(clients);
});


 $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "400px",

        inserting: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,

        data: clients,

        fields: [
            { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
            { name: "Email", type: "number", width: 50 },

            { type: "control" }
        ]
    });
```

is there anyway to present data on a table like in jsgrid?

Answer (score 0):

jsgrid works with any REST service, firebase is not an exception.

In your example data loading happens asynchronously, so when grid is initialized clients data is not loaded yet. To fix the problem initialize grid on `done` of the `$.getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON("/*url of databse*/.json").done(function(data)
     // initialize grid here
)
```

Worth to note that setting grid data with `data` config option is for static scenario. More common way is to define the `controller` (http://js-grid.com/docs/#grid-controller).